# Can't bind a click event on a button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a js newbie.

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul class='selectable-list'>
 <li><a data-id="5" data-type="Content">Test</a></li>
 <li><a data-id="3" data-type="Content">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

I add en event

```
$selectableList = $('.selectable-list a');
$selectableList.click(function(){ 
  console.log(this)
  script.addItem(this); 
});
```

The result is that `this` is a text so I can't get data attributes... why?

Edit:

```
        bindEvents : function bindEvents() {
            $selectableList.click(function(){ 
                console.log(this.attr("data-type"))
                script.addItem(this); 
            });
        }

Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function
```

Comment: No, `this` is not a text, you're mistaken !

Comment: @adeneo I don't know why but is not a DOM node...

Answer (score 1):

.attr is a function provided by jQuery which mean you can only apply it to jQuery objects.

Here in the code snippet you are trying to use it on **this** which belongs to  native javascript and it does not have .attr method associated with it. This **this** object will be the DOM node object that you clicked on.

What you need to do it to wrap your this around $ or jQuery namespace something like

```
$(this).attr("data-type")
```

and you should be good to go

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure where the text you are talking about is coming from. The `this` will be the DOM node that you clicked on. If you wrap it in `$()` you should be able to read the data attribute.

```js
$selectableList = $('.selectable-list a');
$selectableList.click(function(){ 
  
  var anchor = $(this);
  console.log(anchor.data("id"), anchor.data("type"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='selectable-list'>
 <li><a data-id="5" data-type="Content">Test</a></li>
 <li><a data-id="3" data-type="Content">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```